# Scale raster in ArcGIS using raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster-calculator, error-000539, error-999998

I have a raster with values ranging from 0 to 8991130624. This raster is actually the result of a cost distance analysis.

I want to scale the raster to range from 0 to 1 and take the inverse? so that a cell with the highest cost/value (e.g. 8991130624) will now have a value of 0 while a cell with the lowest cost/value (e.g. 0) will now have a value of 1.

I am using raster calculator with the following expression:

1-(x/8991130624)

where I add x to the expression by clicking on the raster from the list of available rasters when using the tool

This is not working and producing an error:
"ERROR 000539: Error running expression; rcexec() :ERROR 999998:Unexpected Error."

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have spaces on either side of the mathematical operators:

```
1 - (x / 8991130624)
```