# How to get the inverse of a raster in ArcMap 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, raster-calculator, raster-conversion

I have a raster ranging from 0 to 80,000. I want to invert this, such that 80000 becomes 0.0000125.

When I use a raster calculator as (1/x) it returns 1s where the were values and blank where there was a zero. While for zero its correct the other values are wrong.

I tried this option [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55028/scale-raster-in-arcgis-using-raster-calculator) `1.0 - (float(x) / 80000.)`, all the values are converted well only that they are scaled. I dont want this scaling, I need the exact inverses how do i go about this?

Comment: Is your raster a floating raster?

Comment: The raster is 16 unsigned integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your raster needs to be "a floating raster" to store decimal values.
Transform your integer raster into a floating one, then run the raster calculator again.